# What do the enclosed numbers represent?

Tags: planetary-science, planet, statistics

A friend asked me what the numbers in the following image represent:

[image]

```
Mercury   8
Venus    15
Earth    61
Mars     33
Ceres    42
Jupiter  42
Saturn  100
Uranus   22
Neptune  57
Pluto    85
```

My (limited) guesses on what the figures could be turned up nothing. I'm guessing since Saturn is 100, that the figures are expressed as a % of whatever the figure is for saturn? I'm pretty stumped for this.

Any idea what the numbers stand for?

Comment: Where does the image come from? It seems to be of a display, so where it was taken could help. One would expect there to be an explanation somewhere nearby. As there is no apparent pattern, it is possible that it relates to a work of fiction or an outside field such as astrology. More information is needed for this to be answerable.

Comment: My friend took the picture and sent it to me asking what it meant. He's located in Britain if that helps.

Comment: [Pinged the puzzling.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30575679#30575679) - perhaps they can help figure this one out

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41617/discussion-on-question-by-sylae-corell-what-do-the-enclosed-numbers-represent).

Comment: FYI, an image search turns up a LOT of hits with the "original" image. For example, https://museumvictoria.com.au/pages/8719/gallery/SolarSystem_2008.jpg

Comment: It's really clear what he is asking : "What do the enclosed numbers represent?"

Comment: @Lordofdark It is not clear what the context of the numbers is however. It may have nothing to do with Space Exploration, or even Astronomy. The on hold text clearly says "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need." This is exactly what is needed. The OP could talk to the friend and see if the friend has more context for the image. If not, the question may be unanswerable.

Comment: @Lordofdark If someone does come up with an answer in the meantime, we could always reopen the question.